# Get all files in sub directories in meteor FS

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I am using Meteor JS. I install FS and Path NPM modules.
How can I get all the files with format ".txt" in sub directories?
I want to get their paths and store it in an array.

I tried to use `fs.readdirSync(path);` but the output is only name of the directory. I need paths of the files.

For example,

sitedir/some/directories/file.txt

Comment: what have you tried to get the pathname? This is a fairly straightforward task and has nothing to do with meteor.

Comment: Can I get the pathname of unknown files? in unknown directories?

Comment: path + filename? You already have the path no?

Comment: I have only the path of parent directory. this parent directory have child directories that I don't know.